# Calculate number of times a "if" statement is true

Tags: java

I want to calculate how often a certain if statement is true:

```
for (int i=0;i<10001;i++){
    int min = 1;
    int max = 6;

    int dice1 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
    int dice2 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));

    //System.out.println(dice1 + " and " + dice2);

    if (dice1==dice2) {
        System.out.println("yes");}
    }
}
```

With this, I want the output to be an integer (sum), for example that states the number of times the number outputted by dice1 and dice2 is the same.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `int sumEqual = 0; ..... ++sumEqual;`....

Comment: ((max - min) + 1)) Will these value changes in your code , If not you can simplify this

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly enough, to count, you need a counter; so let me make a counter proposal:

```
int counterOfTruth = 0;
for ...
  if (...) {
    ... 
    counterOfTruth++;
  }
}

print counterOfTruth;
```

And, seriously: you would be using a more telling name like "counterForIdenticalDiceThrows".

Comment: Going to upvote because everytime I see your posts, I open for the cat. Also this is a better Java way of doing things.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "open for the cat"; but glad it works ;-)

Answer (score 3):

One way that minimises code pollution is to define a counter

`int count = 0;`

*before* the `for` loop, and write `if (dice1 == dice2 && ++count > 0){`

Here I'm exploiting the short-circutting nature of `&&`: `count` is only evaluated (and incremented) if `dice1 == dice2`. Note that `++count > 0` is always `true` so doesn't change the conditional.

It doesn't come out as nicely as it does in C or C++: in those languages you don't need the clunky `> 0`, so perhaps my suggestion is not as idiomatic in Java as it is in C or C++.

Comment: Maybe I am just jealous that you get all the upvotes, but honestly: for java, i find that to be pretty ugly. It adds something to the if condition that has **nothing** to do with the condition itself. In other words: a clean violation of "single responsibility".

Comment: Upvoting too. Not because I like it; but because of the "ah, that would work too" aspect of it.

Comment: @GhostCat: have an upvote, in Java (and in code maintained by non-scientific programmers), I prefer your solution.

Comment: I did this with the following:

Comment: 'for(int i=0;i<10001;i++){
            int count = 0;
            int min = 1;
            int max = 6;

            int dice1 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
            int dice2 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
            
           // System.out.println(dice1 + " and " + dice2);
            
            if(dice1==dice2){
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);}
            
    
    }

Comment: @N.Rosenthal wrong place to define the `count`. Put it outside the loop (and include code in the question via `edit` and not in a comment for the question, or even an answer)

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<10001;i++){
            int count = 0;
            int min = 1;
            int max = 6;

            int dice1 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
            int dice2 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
            
           // System.out.println(dice1 + " and " + dice2);
            
            if(dice1==dice2){
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);}
            
    
    }`

Comment: how do I delete a comment? hahaa new to this forum :/

Comment: @N.Rosenthal there´s a small `X` button next to the edit text

Comment: I'm either really stupid or cant find it, where do I edit a comment? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A very common trick is to use the post-increment operator `++` (which adds one to a variable when invoked) inside your if statement:

```
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10001; i++){
   // The rest of your code here!
      if (dice1 == dice2){
        System.out.println("yes");
        count++;
      }
   }
   System.out.println("The dice were equal " + count + " times.")
```

Comment: even if the intention is clear here, to create a counter, this lets an open room to declare `count` at the wrong spot (looks lik in the loop)

Comment: Good point- ironically I was being more verbose than your comment to try and be clearer about this. Now edited.

Answer (score 0):

> You can always move the common code outside of the loop,This is called **Loop Invariant** code which gives the same value in every iteration like (max-min)+1.

Also, you can move the variable declarations outside of the loop.

```
int min = 1;
int max = 6;
int dice1,dice2;
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0;i<10001;i++)
{
       dice1 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
       dice2 = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));



        if(dice1==dice2)
        {
           counter ++;
           System.out.println("yes");
        }
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: It should be noted that this should all be enclosed in the function including declaration of the `counter` if it's to be used multiple times.